# coordinate change in a list of points

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list(?) of rules (geometrically points) like;

```
pts={{a->3,b->6},...}
```

and I want to apply the logarithm to each **and** change the name, e.g.,

```
ptsNew = {{u -> log(3), v->log(6)},...}
```

I tried Log@@, and also Log//@ but neither even converted the number, much less the name (from x->u and y->v).

Thanks!

PS

Surprisingly, this didn't even work as expected. I was trying it for just the 2nd coordinate but the Log is on the outside of the rule...

```
Table[{u = 4, v = N[Log[s1a[[i]][[2]]]]}, {i, 1, 7}]
```

PPS

Sorry to come back but I just noticed that for my list of points (that came from an NSolve[]),

```
{{a -> -4.38426 - 3.57467 I, b -> 0.92847 - 0.0993489 I}, 
{a -> -4.38426 + 3.57467 I, b -> 0.92847 + 0.0993489 I}, 
{a -> 5.65685 - 2.42731*10^-7 I, b -> -0.707107 - 8.46156*10^-9 I}, 
{a -> -4.38426 + 3.57467 I, b -> 0.532424 + 0.056971 I}, 
{a -> -4.38426 + 3.57467 I, b -> -0.294228 + 0.642985 I}, 
{a -> -4.38426 - 3.57467 I, b -> -0.294228 - 0.642985 I}, 
{a -> -4.38426 - 3.57467 I, b -> 0.532424 - 0.056971 I}, 
{a -> -5.65685 + 2.43458*10^-6 I, b -> 0.707107 + 4.7445*10^-8 I}, 
{a -> 5.65685 + 4.92316*10^-7 I, b -> -0.707107 + 1.71621*10^-8 I}}
```

when I use @J.M. suggestion, I get nine results again, but each result is `doubled';

```
{{{u -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I,  v -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.0685253 - 0.106597 I, v -> -0.0685253 - 0.106597 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I, v -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.0685253 + 0.106597 I, v -> -0.0685253 + 0.106597 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 - 4.29092*10^-8 I, v -> 1.73287 - 4.29092*10^-8 I}, 
{u -> -0.346574 - 3.14159 I, v -> -0.346574 - 3.14159 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I, v -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.624622 + 0.106597 I, v -> -0.624622 + 0.106597 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I, v -> 1.73287 + 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.346574 + 1.99995 I, v -> -0.346574 + 1.99995 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I, v -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.346574 - 1.99995 I, v -> -0.346574 - 1.99995 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I, v -> 1.73287 - 2.45757 I}, 
{u -> -0.624622 - 0.106597 I, v -> -0.624622 - 0.106597 I}}, 
{{u -> 1.73287 + 3.14159 I, v -> 1.73287 + 3.14159 I}, 
{u -> -0.346574 + 6.70973*10^-8 I,v -> -0.346574 + 6.70973*10^-8 I}},
{{u -> 1.73287 + 8.703*10^-8 I,v -> 1.73287 + 8.703*10^-8 I}, 
{u -> -0.346574 + 3.14159 I, v -> -0.346574 + 3.14159 I}}}
```

Not sure if it was `permuting' instead of 'combinating' the 2 arguments or what, but the only answer worked well.

Just in case someone came across this.

Comment: `Thread[{u, v} -> #] & /@ Log[{a, b} /. pts]` ought to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
{u -> Log@a, v -> Log@b} /. pts
```